# Howto: Block visible only if node X is published?

Tags: drupal

With this code I show node in block:

```
print check_markup(node_load(777, NULL, TRUE) -> body);
```

Problem: block displayed even node 777 is unpublished.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may want to check the node's format for your check_markup call, just in case the node uses a non-default input format.

Answer (score 2):

```
$node = node_load(777);
if ($node->status) {
  print $node->body...
}
```